# DB connections are getting exhausted whereas Weblogic connection pool is perfectly fine

Tags: java, sql, oracle, hibernate, stored-procedures

I have faced a typical issue wherein WebLogic connection pool capacity is under the limit, but Oracle DB connections keep on increasing and eventually, hit the max DB connection size and stop responding.

We are using hibernate to call a DB stored procedure to update some records in DB.

```
create or replace procedure UPDATE_TIME
(
   p_alarmId       NUMBER,
   p_clearTime     NUMBER
)
is
   v_errorCode NUMBER := 1;
begin
    while ( v_errorCode != 0 )
    loop
       v_errorCode := 0;
       begin

          update ANNOTATION
          set    PARTITION_TIME=p_clearTime 
          where ANN_ID = (select ANNOTATION_ID from CORE where ID = p_alarmId) and PARTITION_TIME = 0;

          exception
             when OTHERS then
               v_errorCode := 1;
       end;
    end loop;
end;
/
```

And finally, WebLogic transaction times-out after 5 minutes as socket timeout is specified as mentioned below but DB connection never gets free.

```
<url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:31300/oneodb?socketTimeout=300000</url>
```

**Exception:**

```
javax.ejb.EJBException: EJB Exception: ; nested exception is: 
    javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: could not execute native bulk manipulation query
...
        at Caused by: oracle.net.ns.NetException: Socket read timed out
        at oracle.net.ns.Packet.receive(Packet.java:339)
```

Any input is highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I don't know anything about Hibernate, but what kind of exceptions are you expecting that update to fail with? That loop could repeat forever, burning server resources the whole time.

Comment: Thanks William. We removed the loop and caught the exception.

Answer (score 0):

We found the root cause of the issue.

While loop inside the db procedure was not letting the original exception thrown to the application. Once this loop was removed, exception was caught.

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row
```

The inner query specified inside the update command was returning 2 row whereas only 1 was expected. Query has been updated with more constraints and it worked fine. Also, this unnecessary while loop is removed.